# Resolve maven dependency if dependency only contains jar file(and not .pom, .md5, .asc, etc)

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

Is there a way to resolve a maven dependency in the current version of Maven(3.6.2) if the dependency only has a jar and not other artifacts like .pom, .md5, .asc, etc. It used to work fine in version 3.0.X however, it doesn't work anymore in the current version.

Comment: You could generate a simple pom via maven-install-plugin See the docs for details...

Comment: Where do you get a dependency without a pom file? I have never seen that.

Comment: It's a local artifact repo in the company.